# Failed to send url through intent put extra method

Tags: android, android-intent, android-recyclerview

[Got the solution thanks to thomaspsk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40224677/intent-put-extra-method-is-crashing-the-app)

So I am parsing link urls from online database and displaying it in recycler view. I also want to send those urls through `Intent`'s `putExtra()` method

I tried it using

```
Bundle bundle = intent.putExtra("image_link",my_data.getImage_link());
```

but it is not working

here is a full adapter code.
Please also check if I am using click listener on the right position.
I saw some people using it under `ViewHolder`.

```
import android.content.Intent;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.content.Context;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;

import java.util.List;

import com.bumptech.glide.Glide;

import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.ViewHolder> {
    private Context context;
    private List<MyData> my_data;

    public MyAdapter(Context context, List<MyData> my_data) {
        this.context = context;
        this.my_data = my_data;
    }

    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

        View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.recycler_child, parent, false);

        final ViewHolder holder = new ViewHolder(itemView);
        itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                int position = holder.getAdapterPosition();
                Intent intent = new Intent(context, article.class);
                Bundle bundle = intent.putExtra("image_link", my_data.getImage_link());
                context.startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

        return new ViewHolder(itemView);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.description.setText(my_data.get(position).getDescription());
        Glide.with(context).load(my_data.get(position).getImage_link()).into(holder.imageView);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return my_data.size();
    }


    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        public TextView description;
        public ImageView imageView;

        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            description = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView);
            imageView = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.image);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Just a guess: maybe you should try to store the result of "my_data.getImage_link()" into a String, and then you can "Bundle bundle = intent.putExtra("image_link",my_data_string);"

Comment: What error you've got? Imho, you need to call startActivity with Activity as your Context.

Answer (score 0):

To send the data using Bundle simple do the following :

```
Intent intent = new Intent(context,article.class);
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putString("IMAGE_LINK", my_data.getImage_link());
intent.putExtras(bundle); // or intent.putExtra("BUNDLE",bundle); and reveive there : Bundle b = getBundleExtra("BUNDLE");
context.startActivity(intent);
```

To retrieve the data in other activity you can follow :

```
Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
String imageLink = bundle.getString("IMAGE_LINK");
```

Comment: But how should I put image_link in bundle?

Comment: bundle.putString("IMAGE_LINK", my_data.getImage_link()); is not working

Answer (score 0):

first you need to get the item from your list with `get` method and than URL from that item.

```
@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

    View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.recycler_child,parent,false);

    final ViewHolder holder = new ViewHolder(itemView);
    itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            int position = holder.getAdapterPosition();
            Intent intent = new Intent(context,article.class);
            intent.putExtra("image_link",my_data.get(position).getImage_link());
            context.startActivity(intent);

        }
    });

    return new ViewHolder(itemView);
}
```

Comment: app is crashing on click event

Comment: Required: android.os.Bundle
Found: android.content.intent

I have imported android.os.Bundle library

Comment: check my updated answer, you don't need to store extra in bundle to pass it in intent.

Comment: The app is crashing when I click on cardview

Answer (score 0):

code line `private Context context;` in your **MyAdapter** most likely not an Activity context.

You need to pass the Activity when creating MyAdapter with something like:

```
MyAdapter myAdapter = new MyAdapter(callerActivity, my_data);
```

But this susceptible to context leaks.

---

A better way is using a **Listener** which direct the `onClick()` to your **Activity** or **Fragment**.

**First**, create the listener in your Adapter:

```
public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.ViewHolder>   {

  private List<MyData> my_data;

  public MyAdapter(List<MyData> my_data) {
    // this.context = context; // You don't need to use context here anymore.
    this.my_data = my_data;
  }

  ...

  // Define listener member variable
  private static OnItemClickListener mListener;

  // Define the listener interface
  public interface OnItemClickListener {
    void onItemClick(int position);
  }

  // Define the method that allows the parent activity or fragment to define the listener
  public void setOnItemClickListener(OnItemClickListener listener) {
    this.mListener = listener;
  }
  ...
}
```

**Second**, call the listener in your **MyAdapter** `onCreateViewHolder()` when item clicked:

```
@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
  View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.recycler_child,parent,false);
  final ViewHolder holder = new ViewHolder(itemView);
  itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
     @Override
     public void onClick(View v) {
       onItemClick(holder.getAdapterPosition());
     }
   });

   return new ViewHolder(itemView);
}
```

**Last**, you need to implement `MyAdapter.OnItemClickListener` in your Activity or Fragment which use the adapter. Something like:

```
public class YourActivity extends Activity
    implements MyAdapter.OnItemClickListener {

   ...

  @Override 
  public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    // you need to add this after creating the adapter.
    // this only for example.
    MyAdapter myAdapter = new MyAdapter(my_data); // Don't use a context here anymore.
    myAdapter.setOnItemClickListener(this); // Set listener to parent.
  }

  // method implemented from MyAdapter.OnItemClickListener
  @Override 
  public void onItemClick(int position) {
    // Call the intent here
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, article.class);
    Bundle bundle = intent.putExtra("image_link",my_data.get(position).getImage_link());
    this.startActivity(intent);  
  }

  ...
}
```

Comment: If I use OnClick listener on activity/adapter the getActivity position is not working

If I use it on itemView with intent 
  intent.putExtra("image_link",my_data.get(position).getImage_link());

Comment: then the app is crashing if I click on any card

Comment: I forgot to change `my_data.getImage_link()` to `my_data.get(position).getImage_link()` in `onItemClick(int position)` method.

Comment: But my activity is like public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.ViewHolder>   {

Comment: But my activity is like public class
 MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.ViewHolder> {
I can't implement click listener on RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.ViewHolder>

Comment: you don't implement it, but create the interface for it. Implementation need to be done in Activity/Fragment which using the adapter.